# Kendo column on resize dragging weird

Tags: kendo-ui, resize, kendo-grid, drag

My example: http://dojo.telerik.com/irEQo

Problem: When I go about resizing a column I click on the gap between them and drag, at which point the column widths become messed up (See screenshot and video below).

[image]

https://vid.me/TmkP

Answer (score 1):

My Fix:

Instead of using fixed width using pixels values, I set the fixed width using percentages.

Example:
Before

```
{
        field: 'statusId',
        title: 'Type',
        width: 50,
        filterable: true,
        attributes: {
          "class": "someClass"
}
```

After

```
{
        field: 'statusId',
        title: 'Type',
        width: '15%',
        filterable: true,
        attributes: {
          "class": "someClass"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you set a fix width to all columns but the sum of all widths does not match the grid's with. So if you have 3 columns all with width 100px, but your grid is 400px wide, the columns are stretched to e.g.133px each. As soon as you 'grab'  column, the original size (100px) is used which makes the column jump.

This is a Kendo problem so there is no real solution for this (at least I haven't found one), but there are possibilities to avoid the 'jumping':

You can either set no with for one column, this column then fills the rest of the space.

Or add an empty column as last column which then fills the space while your real columns all keep the size they are set to.

To add an empty column just add

```
 {
   field: ""
 }
```

to your columns list.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the benefit does not outweigh the caveats: http://dojo.telerik.com/IXeYa